# non-root non-sudo installation not working; how to install-tl using custom --profile?

Tags: installing, paths, linux

I'm trying to install TeX Live in my home directory in Ubuntu 12.04, where I don't have `sudo` rights. I'm installing from the Live CD.

But `install-tl` always wants to install in `/usr/local/bin` and stops because I don't have the access rights.

In the texlive install documentation, the sentence:

> "`install-tl --profile=profile` does a batch (unattended) installation. To create such a profile file, it's easiest to start with the tlpkg/texlive.profile file which the installer writes at the end of any successful installation."

Sounds to me as if I could only `install-tl` using a custom profile **after** a successful installation, so that for the start I don't see a profile I could overwrite. Using the Unix `find` function I couldn't find anything called `*.profile` in the CD.

How can I call `install-tl` so that everything gets installed in a very usual configuration similar to the `sudo` installation, except that instead of using `/usr/local` or any root-owned directory, everything goes to my `~/.local`,`~/.local/bin`, `~/.local/doc`, `~/.local/etc`, `~/.local/share`, `~/.local/include`, `~/.local/lib`, and  `~/.texlive2014`?

Edit:
@dartbirth and @Andrew Cashner, thanks a lot. It's true that I hadn't read the install-tl ui carefully enough. My console is too narrow and just showed the last lines of the install-tl ui text, hiding the directory configuration part. It's as silly as that. Now the internet installer is running and I hope to be asking for closing this issue very soon. Thanks again.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Related (but not duplicate I don't think, since most answers there require root access): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: No time for a full answer, but running `install-tl -gui=text` (or the wizard, I suppose) gives you the option to change the installation directories... did you try that?

Comment: Why are you using a profile in the first place? I do think one can specify the installation dir in a profile but I do not know how as I never use them. Since you do not have sudo access, why don;t you ask your system admin to install a better LaTeX installation. Seems to benefit more than one user.

Comment: Just look through the installer options carefully and you'll see an option to change the install directory.

Comment: Use the `D` option?